# How to group objects by their enum values?

Tags: java, collections, enums

I would like to write a program which analyses properties of houses in a neighborhood. For this I have 3 enums in my program which include the different properties, i.e. size, color and shape of the houses.

The houses are defined the following way:

```
public House(Size size, Color color, Shape shape) {
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
        this.shape = shape;
    }
```

Now I have an ArrayList with a few hundred different houses and I would like to count how many houses each have which combination of properties (for example "how many houses are big, blue and rectangular?"). If I would create a new ArrayList for each possible combination of these properties I would have more than 30 lists and tons of if-loops in my code.

Is there an easier way to group houses with the same enum values together?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Java Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) to filter your list then produce a count, for example;

```java
long smallRedRectangularHousesCount = houses
        .stream()
        .filter(h -> h.getSize() == Size.SMALL &&
                h.getColor() == Color.RED &&
                h.getShape() == Shape.RECTANGLE
        )
        .count();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's get some example enum values.

```java
enum Size
{ TINY, SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, MANSION }

enum Color
{ BEIGE, BROWN, GREEN, GREY }

enum Shape
{ RECTANGLE, SQUARE, ROUND }
```

I would redefine that class `House` as a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) for brevity and simplicity.

Also, tracking real properties requires additional fields beyond just size, color, and shape. For our purposes here, I will add a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) to identify each individual house.

```java
record House ( UUID id , Size size, Color color, Shape shape ) {}
```

Some sample data.

```java
List < House > houses =
        List.of(
                new House( UUID.fromString( "d23d3532-7e43-441a-ac49-d2bc37d884a2" ) , Size.MEDIUM , Color.BROWN , Shape.RECTANGLE ) ,
                new House( UUID.fromString( "e0e7d84c-8500-4372-a6ac-6b601e50b31e" ) , Size.LARGE , Color.BROWN , Shape.ROUND ) ,
                new House( UUID.fromString( "ab251020-fc2b-4f3a-ae92-4cd6da850ac0" ) , Size.MEDIUM , Color.GREEN , Shape.RECTANGLE ) ,
                new House( UUID.fromString( "c675f75e-335e-418e-b805-d6563c2c6e0f" ) , Size.LARGE , Color.BROWN , Shape.ROUND )
        );
```

If you simply want to search the list for a particular combination of properties, you can use streams to filter as shown in Answer by [Idan Elhalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72410852/642706).

```
long countBrown = houses.stream().filter( house -> house.color().equals( Color.BROWN ) ).count();
```

> 3

For multiple criteria (color and shape as well as size), use the `&&` syntax seen in the other Answer.

Your Question is somewhat confused. You seem to be asking about grouping all houses by all possible combinations of criteria. Doing so would be a good idea if you are doing many mare queries than data changes. Doing the grouping ahead of time is much work, but is worth it if you are doing many queries.

To do the grouping, let's define another record, `HouseProfile`, to contain only the three fields of Size, Color, and Shape. We will use loops to instantiate objects of all possible combinations.

```
record HouseProfile( Size size , Color color , Shape shape ) { }
```

We can determine all possible combinations quite easily. Calling `values` on an enum returns an array of all the named objects on that enum. We can then loop on that array.

We do this for each of your 3 enums: `Size`, `Color`, and `Shape`. As we go through these, we filter the list of houses that match each enum object. We end up with a list of houses that match each combination of enum objects. That list might be empty, or might have houses. We put each list in a `Map`, a collection of key-value pairings. We use `HouseProfile` as the key to our map, leading to a `List` of type `House`.

First define our map, to hold results.

```
Map < HouseProfile, List < House > > housesByProfile = new HashMap <>();
```

Then loop all values of each enum.

```java
for ( Size size : Size.values() )
{
    List < House > sized = houses.stream().filter( house -> house.size.equals( size ) ).toList();
    for ( Color color : Color.values() )
    {
        List < House > sizedAndColored = sized.stream().filter( house -> house.color.equals( color ) ).toList();
        for ( Shape shape : Shape.values() )
        {
            List < House > sizedAndColoredAndShaped = sizedAndColored.stream().filter( house -> house.shape.equals( shape ) ).toList();
            housesByProfile.put( new HouseProfile( size , color , shape ) , sizedAndColoredAndShaped );
        }
    }
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "housesByProfile = " + housesByProfile );
```

If you read through the output, you will find each of three sample houses. Notice that for `HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=BROWN, shape=ROUND]` we have a list of two `House` objects with IDs of "e0e7d84c-8500-4372-a6ac-6b601e50b31e" & "c675f75e-335e-418e-b805-d6563c2c6e0f".

> housesByProfile = {HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=GREEN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=GREEN, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=BROWN, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=BEIGE, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=BROWN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[House[id=d23d3532-7e43-441a-ac49-d2bc37d884a2, size=MEDIUM, color=BROWN, shape=RECTANGLE]], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=BEIGE, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=GREEN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=BEIGE, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=BEIGE, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=BEIGE, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=GREY, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=GREEN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=GREEN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[House[id=ab251020-fc2b-4f3a-ae92-4cd6da850ac0, size=MEDIUM, color=GREEN, shape=RECTANGLE]], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=BEIGE, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=BROWN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=GREY, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=GREEN, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=BROWN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=BROWN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=GREEN, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=GREY, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=GREY, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=BROWN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=BROWN, shape=ROUND]=[House[id=e0e7d84c-8500-4372-a6ac-6b601e50b31e, size=LARGE, color=BROWN, shape=ROUND], House[id=c675f75e-335e-418e-b805-d6563c2c6e0f, size=LARGE, color=BROWN, shape=ROUND]], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=BROWN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=BROWN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=GREY, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=GREY, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=GREY, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=GREEN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=BROWN, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=BEIGE, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=BEIGE, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=BEIGE, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=GREEN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=BEIGE, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=GREEN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=GREEN, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=BEIGE, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=GREEN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=GREY, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=BEIGE, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=BROWN, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=GREY, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=GREY, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=BROWN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=BROWN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=BROWN, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=GREEN, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=GREY, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=LARGE, color=GREY, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=GREEN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=BEIGE, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=GREEN, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=BEIGE, shape=RECTANGLE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MEDIUM, color=GREY, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=GREY, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=SMALL, color=BROWN, shape=SQUARE]=[], HouseProfile[size=MANSION, color=BEIGE, shape=ROUND]=[], HouseProfile[size=TINY, color=GREY, shape=SQUARE]=[]}

Let’s use that map to get a count of houses meeting a combination of criteria.

```
int countLargeBrownRound = housesByProfile.get( new HouseProfile( Size.LARGE , Color.BROWN , Shape.ROUND ) ).size() ;
```

> 2

Comment: Hi, this is amazing, thank you so much! I just have one question: due to the structure of my code, I cannot declare the House as a record, it needs to stay a class (just for context). When I want to filter the different houses with `house -> house.color.equals( color ) ).toList();`, it cannot resolve the color in `house.color`, but when I replace it with the corrsponding getter, the toList() cannot be resolved. Is there any workaround for this? Maybe turning the returned color of the getter into a field itself again? Sorry if I mix things up here

Comment: @Chocolate173 Yes, you could just as well use a conventional class instead of a record. Just call your getter. Be sure your getter returns an enum object. Verify that your pairs of parentheses are balanced. `… house -> house.getColor().equals( color ) ).toList();`

Comment: @Chocolate173 Tip: Your IDE such as IntelliJ can convert a record into a conventional class. That saves you much typing.

Comment: These three nested loops are very inefficient. Just use `houses.stream().collect(Collectors .groupingBy(h -> new new HouseProfile( h.size , h.color , h.shape )));` If you insist an having all combinations, including the absent ones, you’re still better off collecting the existing combinations and adding the absent ones afterwards, instead of filtering the list n×m×o times.